# Spring RESTFul Webservice secure client call using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, restful-authentication, spring-ws

i am going to develop a RESTFul web service using Spring WS.
This service will receive an XML as request which will have authentication information as well as request information.

I need to parse XML request and get those authentication details and authenticate that request.

How can i achieve this functionality using Spring Security? Or any other way for this?

Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only develop contract-first SOAP services with Spring-WS.

> Spring Web Services aims to facilitate contract-first SOAP service
>   development, allowing for the creation of flexible web services using
>   one of the many ways to manipulate XML payloads

Check out: http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/

Take a look at [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18s02.html) page for examples on how to create restful services with Spring 3.x.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As per requirement we have to developed the REST web service using spring-ws.

Comment: Good luck with that (-: I think you'll end up using the Spring 3.0 restful functionality.